# Complex object creation with low coupling

Tags: java, spring

Design question (Java,Spring) of complex object creation with external dependencies required for leaf nodes. When you have a complex object and you need some services to create some parts of the object graph, what would be a good approach to build such object?

Given the following functionality and class structure for building some sort of a report, where LineItem.description need to be resolved by the Purchase.key (your normal localized message to display).

```
class ReportService {

    Report buildReport(Request request, Set<Purchase> purchases) {

        ... build and return Report with logic based on request and purchases ...

    }

}

class Report {
    Header header
    ReportBody body

}

class ReportBody {
    List<LineItem> items
}

class LineItem {
    // Locallized escription
    String description

}

class Purchase {
    String type
    String key
}


// Service used to resolve the message. 
class MessageSource {
    // Return locallized message text found with the given key
    String message(String key, Locale locale) { }
}
```

What would be the elegant way to implement the construction of the Report?

Alternatives that come to my mind:

- Construct entire object in ReportService (or some builder/factory class) and inject the MessageSource to ReportService. Problem with this approach is that then ReportService has high coupling with the entire object graph of Report and its internals and needs all the services which are needed to build child objects.
- Make each class of Report responsible of its children. So ReportService would just:
  return new Report(request,purchases)
  This seems good approach otherwise as parent object only know of its direct children, but we cannot resolve the LineItem descriptions.  We would need to pass the MessageSource (and possible multiple other services) to the POJOs. Injecting services directly to POJOs does not sound reasonable.

So how would you implement this? Also consider keeping it easily unit tested.